# Mock a DB call of a tested class with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying Mockito for unit test.

I have a method :

```
    @Test
    public void checkRG6() {

       Foo foo = new Foo()

     manager.checkFoo(foo);

    }
```

```
public void checkFoo(Foo foo){

        if (StringUtils.isValid(foo)) {
            try {

              getDaoProxy().getComptabiliteDao().getEcritureComptableByRef(
                    pEcritureComptable.getReference());

              ...

            } catch (NotFoundException vEx) {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

I would like to mock this db call :

```
getDaoProxy().getComptabiliteDao().getEcritureComptableByRef(
   pEcritureComptable.getReference());
```

this chained method call the database. could be replaced with:

```
fooRepository.getOneByRef(foo.getRef())
```

But I don't arrive. Is it possible to mock just this call from the checkFoo method ?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/naveenkulkarni029/products-api

Comment: @naveen How is the link related to the question?

Comment: @joffrey What does `getDaoProxy()` returns? Please share complete code.

Comment: You want to mock db calls and I am mocking it in this project

Comment: @Smile I'll edit my topic with this info

Comment: @Naveen Ok ! can you show me where ?